# parsing output from 'attrib' command with an 'if' statement

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, attributes

If I run this command in a bat file:

```bash
attrib "[path\filename]"
```

I might get

```
A    R               [path\filename]
```

How do I use an `IF` statement to test for `R`?

If it is present I want to `exit`, if not, I continue the script.

I have no idea where to go with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
attrib * |findstr /b /R ".....R">nul
if not errorlevel 1 echo Read-only item found
```

Where `*` tests for *any file* and can be replaced by `"[path\filename]"` if you so desire.

This looks for an `R` in the sixth column of a report line, `/b` to select a match on the beginning of the line; `/R` to force "Regular expression" (actually, this is the default) and `".....R"` means 5*(any character)+R.

Note that if the `findstr` succeeds in finding a match, `errorlevel` is set to `0`; otherwise, non-zero and `if errorlevel n` means "if errorlevel is n **or greater than n**"

Caution: If your target does not exist, `findstr` will not be executed so `errorlevel` will remain unchanged from its state before the `attrib` was executed.

You can test for the existence of the target using

```
if exist ...
```

of all things.